# Decimal datatype is rounding the values

Tags: mysql, decimal, sqldatatypes

I have set my `MySQL` field table data type to the `decimal` because from what I have read, I would be able to store the price with commas/dots in the `decimal` data type fields... The problem is that whenever I store any data with the comma or dot, MySQL is rounding it automatically up or down. Eg. When I'm executing the following query:

`UPDATE table SET field = 114.21 WHERE id = 1;`

Then field is set, but the value is rounded to 114, instead of displaying the data I set in the query (`114.21`) - is there any solution for that? Or I should just use other data type?

Comment: Are you binding the value as a parameter?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. AFAIK the dot is the standard notation for decimal values. Using Commas may trigger SQL parse errors or may go unnoticed if the syntactical context allows for a comma to be there.
2. How did you define the precision of the `DECIMAL` column?

   If it is `DECIMAL(10, 2)` it will have a total of 10 numbers of which 2 are decimal values (with 2 decimal rounding meaning that `10.215` is saved as `10.22` and `10.214` becomes `10.21`).

   If it is `DECIMAL(10)` it will not have any decimal values and be rounded to an integer.
3. If you use `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE PRECISION` you don't have to specify the number of decimal values but it has its own flaws.

Answer (score 0):

As Mihai mentioned you need to define the proper precision for the decimal type, e.g. DECIMAL(10,2) for two decimal places.

When inserting a decimal value mySQL will round.

From the docs:

For inserts into a DECIMAL or integer column, the target is an exact data type, so rounding uses “round half away from zero,” regardless of whether the value to be inserted is exact or approximate.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-rounding.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

Well before I have also an issue regarding on what to use on my numbers with decimal points. But problem solved by using **DOUBLE**(10,2) as my **DATATYPE**, and it shows the exact number on the database when you save it. Hope it will help.