# Importing MYSQL table via PHPMyAdmin: DECIMAL type is rounding values

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm having a strange issue importing a MYSQL table into my database via PHPMyAdmin. All values are decimals rounded to one decimal point, for ex. 2.4, 95.5, etc.

I tried setting the row types to DECIMAL, DOUBLE and FLOAT (as described in [Decimal datatype is rounding the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501459/decimal-datatype-is-rounding-the-values)), but each time when I import the values are being rounded to whole integers.

For example, with row type DECIMAL(10,2), I get 96.00 for 95.5, 42.00 for 41.9.

I'm sure there's an easy fix for this, but can't figure out what I'm missing...any help would be appreciated, thanks!