# How to save data in mysql database in original user input

Tags: java, mysql

I create custom app for my assessment, 
So some input and generated data is in floated values, 
So I wont to save that data in MySQL database...as in original values

as a examples- 10.25 must save 10.25 not 10.00 
unfortunately,it save as 10.00 (How to save the data as 10.25) 
But in this case, my code save the values in like previously,

This is the code I used -

```
connectDB();
try{

    String value1 = txt_search_code.getText();
    String value2 = txt_item_code.getText();
    String value3 = txt_discription.getText();
    String value4 = txt_bin_balance.getText();
    String value5 = txt_date.getText();
    String value6 = txt_issued_quantaty.getText();
    String value7 = txt_issued_inno.getText();
    String value8 = txt_arrived_quantaty.getText();
    String value9 = txt_arrived_inno.getText();
    String value10 = txt_final_bin_balance.getText();

    String sql = "Update tbl_stock set No='"+value1+"',ITEM_CODE='"+value2+"',DISCRIPTION='"+value3+"',PREVIOUS_BIN_BALANCE='"+value4+
                 "',DATE='"+value5+"',ISSUED_QUANTATY='"+value6+"',ISSUED_INVOICE_NO='"+value7+"',ARRIVED_QUANTATY='"+value8+"',ARRIVED_INVOICE_NO='"+value9+"',FINAL_BINCARD_BALANCE='"+value10+"'WHERE No='"+value1+"' ";
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Your new records saved Succsessfully!!");

}catch(Exception e){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}

closeDB();
```

this is the MYSQL all statement of the data base

```
SELECT * FROM db_biling.tbl_stock;
    tbl_stock.No, tbl_stock.ITEM_CODE, tbl_stock.DISCRIPTION, 
    tbl_stock.PREVIOUS_BIN_BALANCE, tbl_stock.DATE, 
    tbl_stock.ISSUED_QUANTATY, tbl_stock.ISSUED_INVOICE_NO,     
    tbl_stock.ARRIVED_QUANTATY, tbl_stock.ARRIVED_INVOICE_NO, 
    tbl_stock.FINAL_BINCARD_BALANCE FROM db_biling.tbl_stock;
```

So how can i save the data in original values 
please help me to solve this problem 
**Give me an examples** please 
Thanks

UPDATE

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_stock ( 
    No int(11) NOT NULL, 
    ITEM_CODE varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    DISCRIPTION varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PREVIOUS_BIN_BALANCE decimal(2,0) DEFAULT NULL, 
    DATE varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    ISSUED_QUANTATY decimal(2,0) DEFAULT NULL, 
    ISSUED_INVOICE_NO varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    ARRIVED_QUANTATY decimal(2,0) DEFAULT NULL, 
    ARRIVED_INVOICE_NO varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    FINAL_BINCARD_BALANCE decimal(2,0) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (No) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: What are your column data types? Show the CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `tbl_stock` (
  `No` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ITEM_CODE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DISCRIPTION` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PREVIOUS_BIN_BALANCE` decimal(2,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ISSUED_QUANTATY` decimal(2,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ISSUED_INVOICE_NO` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ARRIVED_QUANTATY` decimal(2,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ARRIVED_INVOICE_NO` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FINAL_BINCARD_BALANCE` decimal(2,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`No`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$

Comment: `DECIMAL(2,0)` is basically an integer, so try instead `DECIMAL(6,2)` which will allow you 2 decimal places ... Or [read the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is on the precision of the datatype

If it is DECIMAL(10, 2) it will have a total of 10 numbers of which 2 are decimal values (with 2 decimal rounding meaning that 10.215 is saved as 10.22 and 10.214 becomes 10.21).

in your case, you used decimal(2,0).. so 10.25 will become 10.

ref:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13501505/7016969